# Error with range filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array called items, and im trying to ng-repeat through a range of the items, such as 0-4 or 5-11, etc. So I tried to create my own custom filter, but it currently is just displaying all the array elements. Can anyone with more knowledge take a look at it. 
html

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:range(0,2)">test {{item}}</li>
</div>
```

filter

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
  $scope.range = function(min, max, step) {
    return function(items) {
      var arr = $scope.items;
      step = step || 1;
      var input = [];
      for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        if (arr[i] != null) {
          input.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return items = input;
    };
  };
});
```

result

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
test 6
test 7
test 8
test 9
test 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create a filter function in angular this function has to return "true" if the given item should be part of the result set and "false" if not.
your function for some reason returns "items = input;" which makes no sense in this context and always resolves to true-ish, which is why all items are going to be displayed.
what you could try is something like

```
$scope.range = function(min, max) {
    return function(item) {
        var i = $scope.items.indexOf (item); 
        return (i >= min && i <= max);
    };
  };
```

please see the docs to angular filter for a understanding of how this function is meant to be used

Comment: var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
$scope.range = function(min, max) {
    return function(item) {
        var i = $scope.items.indexOf (item); 
        return (i >= min+1 && i <= max-1);
    };
  };
});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this fuss, why not use a simple `ng-if` along with `ng-repeat` as below

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index >= 2 && $index <=5">test {{item}}</li>
```